# Posting random-ish tweet with php and codebird

Tags: php, arrays, random

Ok I'm using php and codebird to generate tweets once an entry has been added to my database and here is the sample of whats working well.

```
 $params = array(
    'status' => "Some text " . $name[0] ." some text " . $body
 );
 $reply = $cb->statuses_update($params);
```

This works with ever database entry with no issues.

So now I want to create a few different standard messages and pick one at random. I've been able to partially achieve this with `array_rand()` with the following:

```
$tweets = array(
    "Some text " . $name[0] ." Some text " . $body,
    "Different text " . $name[0] ." different text " . $body,
    "text " . $name[0] ." text " . $body,
    "new text ". $name[0] ." new text " . $body
);

$key = array_rand($tweets, 1);
$params = array(
    'status' => $tweets[$key]
);
```

This seems to be working most the time but it seems that 15% of the time a database entry that should trigger a new tweet doesn't. I've seen every one of my tweet options published as a tweet so it would seem its a random problem with using array_rand(). Thanks in advance